# Selenium - run as a different user?

Tags: selenium

Any way I can set the user principal of webdriver requests in the testInitialize method of a C# implementation?  I'm running on a build server and would like to specify the user that the tests run as.

Comment: Can you give an example, how to run selenium as different user using Remote Control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you have to use selenium with Remote Control instead of using it with WebDriver.

Comment: Can you give an example, how to run selenium as different user using Remote Control?

Comment: Start the remote control as a different user and connect to it through your app.